# Rocket engine propellant/cycle combinations

Tags: engine-design, engines, hypergolics, kerosene

I am trying to determine typical relationships between engine mass and performance for various types of engines, so I'm looking for a broad spectrum of examples to extrapolate from. I'm segregating data by propellant and cycle, and for some categories such as staged combustion kerosene-LOX, I have plenty of data, but for others I have found very few examples.

Other than [Kestrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kestrel_(rocket_engine)), are there any examples of [pressure-fed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure-fed_engine), kerosene/LOX engines with publicly available specifications?

Other than [LR87](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR-87), [LR91](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR91), and the [Viking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_(rocket_engine)) family, are there any examples of [gas-generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-generator_cycle) cycle, hypergolic-storable propellant engines with publicly available specifications?

The specifications I'm interested in are mainly vacuum thrust, vacuum specific impulse, mass, length and diameter. Sea level thrust/ISP and burn time are also nice to have.

Comment: Pressure feed kersoene/LOX was used during early ground tests of the F-1 engine for the first stage of Saturn V when the combustion chamber and nozzle should be tested before the turbine and pumps were available. The very heavy tanks for high pressure were no problem for a ground test.

Comment: I'm really asking about production/flight engines, or at least configurations which were planned to fly.

Comment: @RussellBorogove thank you for posting and answering your own questions, I hope you realize how helpful all of your self-answered questions are :). It's like someone reputable telling you, "hey you should/could think about this" then delivering on the reason behind why it all mattered with an inherently credible source.

Comment: Hah, I was just going through my old questions trying to see if any had answers I should accept, then thought I'd bounty this, then tried googling for the answer again and realized Astronautix was the resource I needed. I always feel cheesy when I self-answer.

Comment: http://www.astronautix.com isn't anything I've ever seen, it's really cool, I'm glad you posted it! Honestly, I'd love a weekly Borogove self-answer; it'd be informative, not cheesy, even on topics you consider blatantly obvious it would help someone. Anything unanswered belongs :).

Comment: [Space Shuttle Orbital Maneuvering System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_Maneuvering_System) (both OMS engines and RCS thrusters) used a monomethyl hydrazine/N2O4 combination. The specs are listed on the wikipedia page, and the OMS engines with a 316 sec ISP were no slouches.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OMS was pressure fed; I’m after hypergolic engines of gas generator driven turbopump type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find on [Astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com) several examples of pressure fed kerosene-LOX engines, some of them built, others "notional":

- [AABS](http://www.astronautix.com/a/aabs.html)
- [Liberty](http://www.astronautix.com/l/libertyengine.html)
- [KSR-3](http://www.astronautix.com/k/ksr-3.html)
- [P4-1](http://www.astronautix.com/p/p4-1sustainer.html)
- [RS-36](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rs-36sustainer.html)
- [PF RP-1](http://www.astronautix.com/p/pfrp-1.html)
- [Sea Dragon-1](http://www.astronautix.com/s/seadragon-1.html)
- [Microcosm 22N](http://www.astronautix.com/m/microcosm22n.html)

As well as some gas generator hypergolics, mostly Russian vernier thrusters:

- [8D423](http://www.astronautix.com/8/8d423.html)/[11D423](http://www.astronautix.com/1/11d423.html) (UR-100)
- [RD-0207](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rd-0207.html) (UR-200 vernier)
- [RD-0230](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rd-0230.html)/RD-0257 (SS-18 vernier)
- [RD-0236](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rd-0236.html)/RD-0251 (SS-19 vernier)
- [RD-854](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rd-854.html)/[RD-861](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rd-861.html) (SS-X-10 orbital, Tsyklon)
- [RD-855](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rd-855.html) (Tsyklon vernier)
- [RD-856](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rd-856.html) (Tsyklon vernier)
- [RD-866](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rd-866.html) (SS-24 MIRV bus)
- [S5.92](http://www.astronautix.com/s/s592.html) (Fregat)
- [XLR-132](http://www.astronautix.com/x/xlr132.html)